Is it legal to use Chrome browser without google sign in or sync sign in?
In my chrome browser when I create my 2nd account maybe didn't google sign in or sync sign in. So, my question is...... Is it legal to use Chrome browser without google sign in or sync sign in? Or is there any mail address where I can Chat with them Directly? Thank you

Not only is it legal, its almost illegal when a company forces you to register an account in order to use their product. Registering an account in order to use a service, maybe, but to use a product, especially if free, not so sure anyone can actually do that, let alone enforce it by law.

When I created my 2nd account in my chrome browser maybe I didn't sign in or sync sign in with my 1st account. If I don't do this, Did I create this account illegally under Google's terms and policies? Can I use this account legally now?

There are no actions you can do regarding account usage with the browser that is considered illegal. Using the browser with multiple profiles with different accounts is all fine, even using different profiles with no accounts is also fine. So yes, you can use it.

No, its not necessary. It helps them to recover your account in bad cases, but if you don't then you can still use their services. Google just tries you to give them as much information about yourself so they can spy more on you, but there's no way for them to actually know if you don't.
